# Как преобразовать 2 подстроки с разделителем, - в TreeMap

Tags: java, коллекции, java-8

Есть файл такого вида, в несколько сот строк, каждая строка, должна быть парой в **TreeMap**.

```
строка1;сторка2
строка3;сторка5
```

Каждая строка, должна соответствовать паре из Map;

Строки нужно прочитать из текстового файла и передать в TreeMap, чтобы они были отсортированы по порядку

```java
    public void read() {

        File dir= new File(path);

       try (
             FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(dir);
             InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)){


           TreeMap <String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();


            while (reader.readLine() != null) {
                System.out.println(reader.readLine());
                // считываем остальные строки в цикле
                String s1 = reader.readLine();

                System.out.println(s1);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            logger.error(FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR, e);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            logger.error(INFO_MESS, e);
        }

        System.out.println("\n" + dir.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
        logger.info(INFO_MESS);


    }
```

пробовал вот такой подход, но без результата

```java
           Map<String, String> kvs =
                   Arrays.asList(reader.readLine())
                           .stream()
                           .map(elem -> elem.split(";"))
                           .filter(elem -> elem.length==2)
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e[0], e -> e[1]));
```

вот так работает

```java
    try (
             FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(directory);
             InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)){

           Map <String, String> book = new TreeMap<>();

           String line;

            while (( line = reader.readLine() ) != null) {

                Map <String, String> map =
                        Arrays.asList(line)
                                .stream()
                                .map(elem -> elem.split(";"))
                                .filter(elem -> elem.length==2)
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e[0], e -> e[1]));
                System.out.println(map);

                for(Map.Entry<String, String> item : map.entrySet()){
                    book.put(item.getKey(), item.getValue());
                }
            }

           System.out.println(book);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            logger.error(FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR, e);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            logger.error(INFO_MESS, e);
        }
```

**Способ громоздкий, может есть покороче вариант ?.**

Comment: пример входа и выхода? К чему вот это `elem.split(":")`, если у вас нет `":"` в вашем примере?

Comment: я просто указал пример, да там должно быть elem.split(";")

Comment: спасибо tym32167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно громоздко... Попробуйте так:

```
public class Test {

    private static String FILE_NAME = "test.txt";
    private static String CHARSET_NAME = "windows-1251";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        Map<String, String> result = Files.lines(Paths.get(FILE_NAME), Charset.forName(CHARSET_NAME))
                .map(l -> l.split(";"))
                .filter(arr->arr.length==2)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k[0], v -> v[1], (v1, v2) -> v2, TreeMap::new));
    }

}
```

Comment: для чего тут нужен `CHARSET_NAME` ? Вроде про кодировку в вопросе нет ничего.

Comment: @tym32167 зачем порождать новые вопросы про MalformedInputException, если это уже сейчас очевидно?

Comment: Мне не очевидно, поясните пожалуйста.

Comment: С кодировкой были вопросы, посмотрите на мой код, я ее использовал. Она нужна и очень.

Comment: дмитрий, можете пояснить вот эту строку : filter(arr->arr.length==2)   и  эту  -   k -> k[0], v -> v[1], (v1, v2) -> v2,

Comment: @skyho  filter(arr->arr.length==2)  - это функциональный аналог условного оператора (if (arr.length==2){}), т.е. далее этого фильтра не проходят массивы, полученные на предыдущем шаге с помощью map, размер  которых не равен 2, потому как коллектор берет только элементы массива  0 и 1 (строка ниже). следующую строку пояснить довольно сложно... я не знаю, насколько хорошо вы разобрались с ФП. для начал прочитайте про функциональные интерфейсы Function, BinaryOperator, Supplier, потому как именно они принимаются в аргументы toMap

Comment: @tym32167 если в данном случае не указывать кодировку, то будет выбрана кодировка по умолчанию, при этом, если она не совпадет, то будет выброшено исключение MalformedInputException. поскольку ответ готовлю я и мне не известно, какая именно кодировка исходного текста у автора вопроса, а для того, кто задает вопрос, может быть неочевидным наличие перегруженного метода  с указанием  кодировки для  Files.lines, на мой взгляд, лучше использовать именно метод с указанием кодировки.

Comment: А, я понял, то есть вы использовали кодировку вашего файла. Я пересмотрел вопрос, там у автора было `InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, потому ему наверное utf подойдет. Но за пояснения спасибо.

Comment: @tym32167 не за что